# Flex/AIR ComboBox is slow to expand

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm using a `mx.controls.ComboBox` which holds 2-5 values. When the ComboBox is clicked, the possible choice are drawn below it.  There seems to be some kind of transition that opens the ComboBox slowly. With Flex (in a browser), it takes 200-300 msec to open. With AIR, it seems to take longer, and opens in a jerky manner.

Someone at Adobe probably thought they were being cute, but the effect (especially in AIR) just looks lame.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: It seems odd that the ComboBox open would take a long time.  Are you using a custom itemRenderer?  Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mx `ComboBox` has two styles which control the [open](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#style%3aopenDuration)/[close](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html#style%3acloseDuration) duration.

```
<mx:ComboBox openDuration="0" closeDuration="0" />
```

However, the fact that this animation plays so poorly does seem odd. In addition to which version of the Flex SDK you're using, you might also specify if this is a mobile AIR app or not.